# persistence of checkbox values

Tags: javascript, checkbox, persistence, back

I have a page with several checkboxes.  I check a few of them and go to the next page, when I come back on this page, these checkboxes need to remain checked as they were before navigating to another page.  Need to do it with Javascript.  Any clue??

Answer (score 4):

If you're limited to JavaScript only and no server side language I think you are left to read/writing cookies to maintain the state.  As others have referenced, server side technologies are much better at this but if you must:

JavaScript cookie sample code (reference: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) :

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to persist them between page-requests. You can use sessions or cookies to do this. What type of server are you working on, and with what type of server-side language?

Previous questions on SO have address writing/reading cookies from JavaScript.

- [Getting or Settings Cookies with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860962/getting-or-setting-cookies-with-javascript)
- [What is the "Best" way to GET and SET a single cookie value using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260749/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-and-set-a-single-cookie-value-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any reasonably complicated way to do it without having any access to the server-side code, because at the minimum you **need** to install your code and also identify the HTML controls e.g. in order to check them. I 'm giving reasonable code that does what you want below.

Important notes:

1. The code **requires** that each checkbox is given a distinct id attribute.
2. The check state is stored in a cookie named 'JS_PERSISTENCE_COOKIE'. It would be better to store the name of this cookie in a variable instead of hardcoding it in a couple of separate places as I have done. What kind of variable should store the name depends on your app and requirements.
3. It would be better to package the code inside an object instead of as a bunch of free functions as I have done. However, this is not relevant to your initial question.
4. After clicking some checkboxes, you can simulate "navigating back to this page" by hitting CTRL+F5. F5 alone is not enough.

Here's the code and some sample HTML for testing:

```
<body onload="restorePersistedCheckBoxes()">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check1" onclick="persistCheckBox(this)" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="check2" onclick="persistCheckBox(this)" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="check3" onclick="persistCheckBox(this)" />
    <input type="button" value="Check cookie" 
           onclick="alert(document.cookie)" />
    <input type="button" value="Clear cookie"
           onclick="clearPersistenceCookie()" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // This function reads the cookie and checks/unchecks all elements
        // that have been stored inside. It will NOT mess with checkboxes 
        // whose state has not yet been recorded at all.
        function restorePersistedCheckBoxes() {
            var aStatus = getPersistedCheckStatus();
            for(var i = 0; i < aStatus.length; i++) {
                var aPair = aStatus[i].split(':');
                var el = document.getElementById(aPair[0]);
                if(el) {
                    el.checked = aPair[1] == '1';
                }
            }
        }

        // This function takes as input an input type="checkbox" element and
        // stores its check state in the persistence cookie. It is smart
        // enough to add or replace the state as appropriate, and not affect
        // the stored state of other checkboxes.    
        function persistCheckBox(el) {
            var found = false;
            var currentStateFragment = el.id + ':' + (el.checked ? '1' : '0');
            var aStatus = getPersistedCheckStatus();
            for(var i = 0; i < aStatus.length; i++) {
                var aPair = aStatus[i].split(':');
                if(aPair[0] == el.id) {
                    // State for this checkbox was already present; replace it
                    aStatus[i] = currentStateFragment;
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!found) {
                // State for this checkbox wasn't present; add it
                aStatus.push(currentStateFragment);
            }
            // Now that the array has our info stored, persist it
            setPersistedCheckStatus(aStatus);
        }

        // This function simply returns the checkbox persistence status as
        // an array of strings. "Hides" the fact that the data is stored
        // in a cookie.
        function getPersistedCheckStatus() {
            var stored = getPersistenceCookie();
            return stored.split(',');
        }

        // This function stores an array of strings that represents the 
        // checkbox persistence status. "Hides" the fact that the data is stored
        // in a cookie.
        function setPersistedCheckStatus(aStatus) {
            setPersistenceCookie(aStatus.join(','));
        }

        // Retrieve the value of the persistence cookie.
        function getPersistenceCookie()
        {
          // cookies are separated by semicolons
          var aCookie = document.cookie.split('; ');
          for (var i=0; i < aCookie.length; i++)
          {
            // a name/value pair (a crumb) is separated by an equal sign
            var aCrumb = aCookie[i].split('=');
            if ('JS_PERSISTENCE_COOKIE' == aCrumb[0]) 
              return unescape(aCrumb[1]);
          }
          return ''; // cookie does not exist
        }

        // Sets the value of the persistence cookie.
        // Does not affect other cookies that may be present.
        function setPersistenceCookie(sValue) {
            document.cookie = 'JS_PERSISTENCE_COOKIE=' + escape(sValue);
        }

        // Removes the persistence cookie.
        function clearPersistenceCookie() {
            document.cookie = 'JS_PERSISTENCE_COOKIE=' +
                              ';expires=Fri, 31 Dec 1999 23:59:59 GMT;';
        }
    </script>

</body>
```