# simplify font size toggle

Tags: javascript

This is my first post here. I think

I want this script to only switch between two sizes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var min=10;
var max=18;
function increaseFontSize() {

   var p = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
   for(i=0;i<p.length;i++) {

      if(p[i].style.fontSize) {
         var s = parseInt(p[i].style.fontSize.replace("px",""));
      } else {

         var s = 10;
      }
      if(s!=max) {

         s += 1;
      }
      p[i].style.fontSize = s+"px"

   }
}

function decreaseFontSize() {

   var p = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
   for(i=0;i<p.length;i++) {

      if(p[i].style.fontSize) {
         var s = parseInt(p[i].style.fontSize.replace("px",""));
      } else {

         var s = 10;
      }
      if(s!=min) {

         s -= 1;
      }
      p[i].style.fontSize = s+"px"

   }
}
</script>
```

So I'd be super happy if someone could remove the 80% of the script that is unneeded for me. (No, really, I am that noob.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what makes you think 80% fo the code is not needed?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: so if your open to working with a js library such as jquery i could do that in 10 lines or so.  and even less if i was true in assuming there would be two buttons or links - one for each of the font sizes

Comment: Try my answer and let me know if it fails. if it works please accept as answer

Comment: Well, maybe not as much as 80, but the counting should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you need this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HrgkY/)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var min=10;
var max=18;
function togalFontSize() {

   var p = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
   for(i=0;i<p.length;i++) {

      if(p[i].style.fontSize) {
         var s = parseInt(p[i].style.fontSize.replace("px",""));
         if(s==max) {
              s = min;
          }else{
             s =  max;
          }
      } else {

         var s = 10;
      }

      p[i].style.fontSize = s+"px"

   }
}

</script>
```

Or if you want 2 functions (May bebecuase you have 2 buttons to switch between them..)
**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/HrgkY/1/)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var min=10;
var max=18;
function increaseFontSize() {

   var p = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
   for(i=0;i<p.length;i++) {

       p[i].style.fontSize = max+"px"

   }
}

function decreaseFontSize() {

   var p = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
   for(i=0;i<p.length;i++) {
      p[i].style.fontSize = min+"px"

   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it very easily with jQuery and some CSS classes, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/redders6600/e3FGs/

Javascript:

```
$('#small').click(function(){
  $('td').removeClass('big').addClass('small');
});

$('#large').click(function(){
  $('td').removeClass('small').addClass('big');
});
```

CSS:

```
td.small{
  font-size:10px;
}
td.big{
  font-size:18px;
}
```

Comment: That is very nice as well. I might use that for something some day. I don't know the first thing about jQuery though. Big thanks again ya all! Respect.

Comment: No probs - if you're doing any web development I'd strongly advise having a look at jQuery. You won't regret it - it makes life *much* easier. It's kind of a staple for most people these days..